# Android Studio Unit Tests With Coverage Showing 0% On Everything

Tags: android-studio, android-testing

I'm trying to check my unit test coverage, all my tests are passing, but when I run the tests with 'Run Tests With Coverage' by right clicking on my test file, when it completes, everything comes back as 0%?

Looks like it's supposed to just work reading https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html and can't find anything saying why it would be returning 0% for everything?

Is there some hidden setting I'm missing to get this working?

Answer (score 15):

Go to `Run->Edit Configuration->Code coverage`. 
Add your package/class for which you want to run tests, in **Packages and classes to record coverage data** section.

Also, check **Enable coverage in test folders** option.

Click `Apply` and `Ok`. Re-run your tests with coverage.

Comment: I don't ->Code coverage option